# organizare archive empty after build to archive in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to build project to archive but after it succeed and I check it in the window>organizare the archive there is empty. Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: Sometime it will reflect after 2 minitue or Please close xcode and open it again it will automaticaly display

Comment: @hardikbar unfortunately it didn't worked for me. Is there any chance its something in the 'build settings'? or some issue with 'pods' ? I read something but not quit sure how to implement the solutions as the answers is for very old version of xcode